# Why npm commands show such behaviour?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, node-modules, mern

```
$ npx create-react-app myform
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Amoory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\bin\expo.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
```

When i run any npm command

I have tried to reinstall node js again and again but not works for me. Also removed package lock.json but that also not works. My commands should be working properly but it seems there is issue .
I have tried to run npx create-react-app myform,  npm start but they are not running succesfully.

Comment: No idea what the `expo` command is supposed to be or how you installed it but [the guide](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/) says to use `npx create-expo-app my-new-project`

Comment: npx create-react-app aso giving me the same issue. what about that?